# Server unable to find public folder in rails 3 production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the latest rails 3 beta. The app works fine in development mode, but when I start the server in production mode via `rails server -e production`, it seems that the `public` folder can't be found. I get error messages like:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/jquery.js"):
```

And similar messages for everything that should be in the `public` folder.
I've tried this with both mongrel and webrick. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

editing config/environments/production.rb and setting this line:

config.serve_static_assets = true

Comment: This really helped me. But if you set it to false, Will the HTTP server (say Apache or something) will serve these files? How does apache know which URLS to hand over to the ruby runtime, and which it can serve? Im a roob noob

Comment: @Zasz See the nginx configuration [here](http://www.talkunafraid.co.uk/2010/09/getting-set-up-with-ruby-and-rails/). It will first find whether the file exists, and deliver the request to rails only if it does not.

Comment: worked like a charm, Thanks. But consider to change it to default after deploying your app. the `serve_static_assets` will be removed in Rails 5.

Answer (score 1):

nginx, unicorn and apache will do this automatically. be sure to change this back to false if you are deploying using these servers.

Comment: using unicorn_rails (intranet environment) had to set config.serve_static_assets = true