# Cannot access the pictures uploaded by Carrierwave versions in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, carrierwave, production

This is my Uploader：

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process :resize_to_fit => [nil, 600]

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [150,150]
  end

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  def filename
    if original_filename
      @name ||= Digest::MD5.hexdigest(current_path)
      "#{@name}.#{file.extension}"
    end
  end

end
```

In `production.rb`, I set **`config.serve_static_assets = false`**.

And I then deployed this project on a production server(Nginx + Passenger) using Capistrano. When I upload a picture, it will generate 2 copies under the `/home/deploy/Gallary/current/public/uploads/picture/photo/` dir, just as following shows:
[image]

And I can access the first one through browser(because this one is the default file which Carrierwave generated), while the second one(generated by `version :thumb`) threw a exception just like this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/picture/photo/49/thumb_6d9596c7449d3714eadb74b9c71beec2.jpg")
```

Actually this file `thumb_6d9596c7449d3714eadb74b9c71beec2.jpg` does exist in the dic right there.

So, what's wrong? And what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Found the answer in another thread.
So try this:

[Server unable to find public folder in rails 3 production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786344/server-unable-to-find-public-folder-in-rails-3-production-environment)

Worked for me

Comment: I think I've solved this problem yeas age, but I don't think I can remember the solution now. By the way, the method you mentioned above didn't work for me.